# Possible to change fixed byte value of date datatype in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Can any one help me .. if is it possible to change the fixed byte type of 7 byte for date datatype from oracle by default for sysdate?

can we change it into 8? bcoz i learn somewhere by default it can be 7 or 8?

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have problem with view i had created for my reports, i used date data type in my java program and when i tried to save and fetch data from oracle views of my report 2 of the reports working fine as they have date datatype of 8 byte but one view have date datatype of 7 byte .. it is not working. I tried many things but i dnt know how to fix out it.

Answer (score 0):

The storage size of dates cannot change.  The difference between 7 and 8 bytes depends on the context.  A date literal or date expression uses 8 bytes but a stored date always uses 7 bytes.

```
create table table1(a date);
insert into table1 values(date '2000-01-01');

select
    dump(a) variable,
    dump(a+1) expression,
    dump(sysdate) "SYSDATE",
    dump(date '2000-01-01') literal
from table1;

VARIABLE:   Typ=12 Len=7: 120,100,1,1,1,1,1
EXPRESSION: Typ=13 Len=8: 208,7,1,2,0,0,0,0
SYSDATE:    Typ=13 Len=8: 222,7,7,19,1,18,20,0
LITERAL:    Typ=13 Len=8: 208,7,1,1,0,0,0,0
```

This means a `DATE` in a view may appear to be either 7 or 8 bytes.

```
create or replace view view1 as 
select a a, a+1 a_1, sysdate a_sysdate, date '2000-01-01' a_literal
from table1;

select dump(a), dump(a_1), dump(a_sysdate), dump(a_literal) from view1;

A:         Typ=12 Len=7: 120,100,1,1,1,1,1
A_1:       Typ=13 Len=8: 208,7,1,2,0,0,0,0
A_SYSDATE: Typ=13 Len=8: 222,7,7,19,1,34,47,0
A_LITERAL: Typ=13 Len=8: 208,7,1,1,0,0,0,0

select column_name, data_type, data_length
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'VIEW1';

COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE  DATA_LENGTH
-----------  ---------  -----------
A            DATE                 7
A_1          DATE                 8
A_SYSDATE    DATE                 8
A_LITERAL    DATE                 8
```

I've never heard of this `DATA_LENGTH` discrepancy causing problems before.  If it's truly the reason for a bug, a possible workaround would be to create the column as `A+0` instead of just `A`.  But keep in mind that converting a regular column to an expression is a bad idea - it can negatively impact index access, partition pruning, and optimizer estimates.

Comment: thank you joenarles, I have issue with my date datatype in one database of 3 views it showed me 7 bytes and 8 bytes date datatype???